# How to call a function with no output in an expression in matlab

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, cell-array

### Short version

Is there a way to call a function (or a method to that effect) within an expression if it doesn't return anything? Say we have an expression `a(o) + b(o)` and we want to call `c(o)` in the same expression when `c` doesn't have an output. For instance if `c` had a return value one could use a dummy function like `g = @(x) 0;` and use `a(o) + b(o) + g(c(o))` to call `c(o)`. But that doesn't work if there is no return value.

### Long version

I have an anonymous function that calls one function with no output like this:

```
f1 = @(obj, s) noout1(obj, s.x, s.y);
```

and I call it using `f1(o, s)`. Now I want it to invoke two functions. If they had outputs I could put them in a cell array like this

```
f2 = @(obj, s) {noout1(obj, s.x, s.y); noout2(obj, s.z)};
```

and call `f2(o, s)`, but this obviously doesn't work if `nargout==0`. The only solution I have now is to collect the anonymous functions in a cell-array and call them separately:

```
f = {@(obj, s) noout1(obj, s.x, s.y); @(obj, s) noout2(obj, s.z)}
```

and use

```
cellfun(@(x) x(o, s), f);
```